# Ignore homebrew when using Chef Solo and Berkshelf

Tags: chef-solo, berkshelf

I am using Chef Solo to provision a Vagrant machine and Berkshelf to install the cookbooks. I am using a Linux host (Ubuntu).

I want to use the mysql cookbook; but when I add:

```
cookbook 'mysql'
```

Berkshelf installs `homebrew` as a transitive dependency. Chef-solo loads everything and it fails because I am in Linux.

Is there any way to ignore the `homebrew` package when installing or loading cookbooks?

Note: I have tried to use

```
group :ignore do
  cookbook 'homebrew'
end
```

But when I run `berks install --without ignore` it returns an error:

```
ERROR: berks install was called with arguments
```

Comment: It looks like you found a solution. Please mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was not the homebrew package; it was the error it throwed.

Using vagrant-omnibus to update Chef to the latest version removed the error and allowed me to finish the installation correctly.